# Angular Chrome not allowed to load local resource

Tags: angular, google-chrome, deployment

I am getting the following errors when I open my webpage after deploying my Angular app.

[image]

I know there are other solutions that say to add the 3 slashes to my HTML, but when I click on the first error, it takes me to this line
[image]

The images that I have loaded in website are all used like
`<img src="assets/img/image1.jpeg" alt="image1" />`
So how do I add `File:///` to these images?

I have used `c:\Program Files (x86)\google\chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`, and Chrome will open up, but the webpage still has the same errors.

Comment: What is base href set to inside index.html..?

Comment: inside the ```index.html```, I have ```<base href="C:/Program Files/Git/harp/" />```.

Comment: Well.. that explains..? Why..?

Comment: does the ```base href``` need to be the same in all the ```index.html``` files? Inside the main ```index.html```, I have ```<base href="/" />```. Inside the ```dist``` folder, ```<base href="/harp/" />```, and then the other one mentioned  is in the ```docs``` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are directly opening the `index.html` file in the source of you Angular project. You should instead run `ng serve` in the root folder of your project (the folder with the `angular.json` file in).